# firebase realtime update security rules without auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm developing, just to learn, a private app for my family, so no distribution, no play store etc, just for us... the problem is that firebase needs a security rules to use firebase, there are a couple of similar questions like this, the difference is that in my case it's useless authenticate the users, I have just a list that needs to be shared with everyone, and everyone could read and write this list.
So, how should I update the security rules in this case? If I don't do it, I won't be able to connect to that database anymore

Comment: There are many questions covering how to secure a database without requiring the users to sign in already: 
https://www.google.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-security%5Dfirebase-realtime-database%5D+public+database+without+authentication+site:stackoverflow.com I recommend trying something of these, and posting back with more details if you run into problems implementing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not advising this strategy but the question states

> in my case it's useless authenticate the users

and

> a list that needs to be shared with everyone, and everyone could read
> and write this list

If that's the case and you want your database to be wide open where anyone can read and write, here's the answer

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Again, not recommended for any use case but it'll do the trick.

This can sometimes be useful when you are just getting started and want to read and write some data and not worry about authentication.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to use Firebase Auth if you want to use Security Rules only. If you don't want to use Firebase Auth then you would have to use Cloud Functions or secure server environment to then use Firebase Admin SDK.

**What the flow looks like when you use Firebase Auth?**

You can create a separate node in your Firebase Realtime Database containing UIDs of your users. (You must be using Firebase Authentication for this). The node may look something like:
[image]

Then you can set your rules to something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'admin'",
    ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'admin'"
  }
}
```

Now when any user attempts to read/write to your database, the action will be allowed only if their UID is in that node.

**How do I restrict access with Cloud functions?**

Here you have complete freedom of how things should work. It could be your personal password that you ask your users to enter while requesting data or something else.

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (data.password !== "yourSuperSecretPassword@123") {
    return {status: 401, error: "Unauthorized"}
  }
  // fetch data and return
});
```

Though you cannot prevent unwanted access to your db only using Firebase Security Rules without Firebase Authentication.

Comment: The OP is asking about Firebase Rules, not Firebase Auth or Cloud Functions. "it's useless authenticate the users" per the question.